# Duplicate a part of the line and add it to the end of the line with a separator

Tags: notepad++

I know it sounds confusing but this is what I want.

> ABC@123: to the changed to ABC@123:ABC

Basically, I need to replicate the texts before the "@" and paste it at the end of the line. Is there any command that can be implemented in the Notepadd++ ?? And the file has more than 100K lines, so please suggest me easy solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: Im sorry, I used excel before this. It has lines limit and besides it takes more time. Not tried anything in notepadd++

Comment: Macros and column editing maybe helpful [Read here](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/series/notepad-tips-tricks/)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^@]+)@.+$`
- Replace with: `$0$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    ([^@]+)     # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not @
    @           # @ character
    .+          # 1 or more any character
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0      # the whole match
$1      # content of group 1 (everything before @)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks bro. It literally saved me tons of time.

Comment: @mjdaran: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)